# Where to edit Asynchronous Rendering reportviewer property

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, config, ssrs-2012

I'm using SSRS and I want to know where to edit this property - Asynchronous Rendering on a whole server level.  The property is outlined here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090.aspx. Why can't they just put where to edit the property as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer Height="100%" ID="rptViewer" runat="server" SizeToReportContent="false" AsyncRendering="true" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```